# Rough estimation of power consumption in an electronic design

Tags: power, integrated-circuit

I want to get a rough estimation of the power that my design is going to need. Is it sane to calculate the power of every IC component based on values in DC Characteristics in the corresponding datasheet, add them together and get a rough yet reasonable value or will I be totally off?

EDIT:

DC Characteristics have 3 columns minimum, typical and max. I will use various combinations based on the use of every IC in a given state. I thought it was clear in the original question that I will use *values* (which include min, typ, max) from DC Characteristics table, not the max values per se, but apparently it is not.

Comment: How should we know? We don't know what kind of ICs you use, and how you use them. If you, for example, only use LED drivers near their maximum power, then sure, that's going to be close. If you, for example, have a microcontroller and let it sleep for 99.5% of time, no, this is going to be completely wrong. Obviously, maximum ratings are maximum ratings and nothing else.

Comment: The absolute maximum ratings may be much different than the typical power consumption of a component; they should not be used to get an estimate of a design's total power. You need to do more work than that.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson You are right, it was my mistake, I confused DC Characteristics table (which includes min, typ, max) with the Absolute Maximum Ratings table. Down votes totally justified.

Comment: @Marcus Müller I did make a mistake in the original question, I updated and clarified. The reason I am not stating the IC components is because I wonder if this can be applied as a general practice, not only in this particular situation.

Comment: Also keep in mind that current will vary with operating temperature. There are a lot of variables here - this question is likely un-answerable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the maxima (from the normal operations sections) of your ICs will yield a (very conservative) upper bound on your current consumption.

To get at a more realistic value you can either measure, or figure out how the actual values vary with the circumstances. Power voltage, temperature, operating mode, and clock frequency often have a big impact.

Start with the list of the power consumptions of all your componets, sorted from high to low. Concentrate of the top entries, you can probably ignore the tail of the list. The 'attack' on the individual components requires experinece, skill and insight, and depends a lot on the type of component.

In a comment you mention the AT25SF041. Its current depends on its mode of operation (power-down, stand-by, active). The conservative estimate is that it is always active (max from the table: 16 mA). If this puts it on top of the list, you need to get more info about how it is used.

If you have a lot of components that attribute roughly the same current, and you can live with < 100% working products, you could use the typical values instead of the max ones, or do a distribution-based addition (assuming some distribution..).

Another interesting aspect is whether you need the average of the peak power consumption. A good design probably needs to take both into account.

PS thumbs-up for using the normal-operation values, be be aware that we see too many questions (and sadly even answers!) here that use the "absolute maxiuma", which are almost never relevant.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't just take current and voltage values from the dc characteristics table and multiply them. The problem with this approach is that a typical device cannot meet those maximum current and voltage ratings **at the same time**. Your calculations will be grossly incorrect.

Consider a 2N3904 transistor. The maximum \$V_{CE}\$ is 40V, the maximum \$I_C\$ is 200mA. Multiplying those gives a power dissipation of 8W, which an order of magnitude greater than what this transistor can actually dissipate in air at room temperature.

Comment: I agree with what you said for this specific example. But I will provide you with another, just to elaborate on my thinking. One of the components I am working with is [AT25SF041](https://www.adestotech.com/wp-content/uploads/DS-AT25SF041_044.pdf). On p.33, table 12.3 it lists various currents according to operation. Since I know my input voltage (3.3V) and when I perform a specific operation, I assume I can calculate the power at that state.

Comment: But what assumptions does this table make about the output pins? If you have output pins then they will be consuming power and I'm pretty sure the table you cite doesn't try to guess what they are doing.

Comment: The aforementioned IC is a flash memory that communicates the data via SPI interface. So, the mentioned currents for when performing a specific operation under specific circumstances (input voltage, operating frequency) I am pretty sure that take into account the output pins since in this IC they do a very specific operation - implement the SPI. If another IC has a general purpose output pins, then yes, I  agree with you, you have to take account what these pins drive.

Comment: Well, you have changed the question now. Your original question asked about "all of the ICs". It's not fair to use single chip as an example and then assume you can extrapolate to the entire system. And I would not assume that the power consumed by the pins is included in the datasheet values unless that is specifically stated.